# Find all vertices within the view, could the script be faster?

Tags: scripting

The number of vertices of the test model is: 126290

```py
import bpy
from bpy import data as D
from bpy import context as C
from bpy_extras import view3d_utils
import bmesh
from mathutils import Vector, bvhtree, Matrix
from math import radians, floor
import time

def get_view_regions(context):
    screen = context.screen
    view_region = None
    view_region_3d = None
    for a in screen.areas:
       if a.type == "VIEW_3D":
            view_region_3d = a.spaces[0].region_3d
            for reg in a.regions[:]:
                if reg.type == "WINDOW":
                    view_region = reg
                    break
            break
    return view_region, view_region_3d

def matrix_screen_to_matrix_world(rv3d, v3d_0_0):
    rvm = rv3d.view_matrix.copy()
    v3d_0_0 = rvm @ v3d_0_0
    return (
        rvm.Translation(-v3d_0_0)
        @ rvm
    )
    
region, rv3d = get_view_regions(C)

def get_vert_idx_in_screen(obj, v3d_0_0, v3d_w_h, rv3d, vertices=None):
    if vertices is None:
        vertices = obj.data.vertices
    matrix = obj.matrix_world
    M = matrix_screen_to_matrix_world(rv3d, v3d_0_0)
    idxs = []
    v3d_w_h = M @ v3d_w_h
    w = v3d_w_h[0]
    h = v3d_w_h[1]
    M = M @ matrix
    for vert in vertices:
        p = M @ vert.co
        isInView = True
        if p[0] < 0 or p[0] > w or p[1] < 0 or p[1] > h:
            isInView = False
        if isInView:
            idxs.append(vert.index)
    return idxs

obj = bpy.context.active_object  
start = time.time() 
v3d_0_0 = view3d_utils.region_2d_to_origin_3d(
            region, rv3d, (0,0))
v3d_w_h = view3d_utils.region_2d_to_origin_3d(
            region, rv3d, (region.width, region.height))
 
vert_idxs = get_vert_idx_in_screen(obj, v3d_0_0, v3d_w_h, rv3d)
end = time.time()
print(end - start, len(vert_idxs))
```

out: 0.18569016456604004 126290

or a better way?

Thanks

Comment: Using kdtree or bvhtree should be faster. Try to use one of them

Comment: @Crantisz I can't figure out how to use the api they provide

Comment: @Crantisz I mean, I don't know how to do what I want to do with those APIs